# ms access "LIKE" operator in ms access does not work in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I hope someone can shed some light on this strange behavior.
I have a very simple sql statement thus:

```
"SELECT TOP 1 PartRefID FROM Parts WHERE PartDescription LIKE '*Backshell*' AND ParentID = 2097"
```

which is executed scalar.
when I enter this in the access query editor it works just fine and returns the expected value.
however, when I run it from within some vb.net code it always returns zero.
can anyone tell me why this is the case?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using .net, you have to use the % sign - it more of a ANSI standard, and this works with jet/ace (access) data engine also.

So, when writing .net code as opposed to VBA, then you are to use % for wild cards - not *. In fact, even in Access VBA, if you were to use ADO (as opposed to the more common and recommended DAO - then even in VBA + ADO, you have to use % in place of *).

so in fact most sql syntax uses %. For ADO, or now what is called ado.net? Then % is to be used.

However, inside access? You can turn on ANSI compatibility - but it WILL make a huge mess of existing access applications - so I don't recommend doing this (enabling Access ANSI sql compatibility mode).

You can quite much assume for "most" software outside of Access - EVEN when hitting the Access database, you use % for wild cards. The only exception here is if one was to use DAO directly as a reference library, and I STRONG recommend you don't do this.

so try using % - and all should be find and well.

Comment: frigging awesome, it works! silly me thinking an asterisk meant "wildcards". what made it most confusing was the fact that the asterisks worked in the query editor without complaint. Thanks!

Comment: Well, inside of access - yes you still need to use the * - and that includes in-line SQL you use with VBA - so easy to mess up! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace *

```
"SELECT TOP 1 PartRefID FROM Parts WHERE PartDescription LIKE '%Backshell%' AND ParentID = 2097"
```